# PrinWriter not Working in servlet

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am new to servlets. Can anyone tell me why this line:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
```

is not working, as shown in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1zzc.png)? I saw in youtube tutorial (simple hello world program in servlet), they exactly do the same, but in my case it's not working. Why?

Comment: Did you import PrintWriter using 'import java.io.PrintWriter'?

Comment: Always, always, always post the error message, as text in your question. We shouldn't need to click on a link (unhelpfully titled "enter image description here") to know what error you're seeing.

Comment: ok.I will remember it next time jon Skeet and thanks Mattias its working after putting 'import java.io.PrintWriter'....

Answer (score 0):

Every time you use any classes of java use `import` statement inorder to use libraries, in above question I am sure you are missing

```
import java.io.PrintWriter
```

at the start of class. alternatively use Ctrl+Space on error area due to which eclipse will automatically imports required libs.